# Want to create Folder in File Manager of App but couldn't

Tags: android, file

Folder is creating Successfully but the location is something like **storage/emualted/0**

> I'm using Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory methods

I want to create publicily available folder which i could save my app's data what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Context#getFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html?hl=en#getFilesDir()) or[Context#getCacheDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html?hl=en#getCacheDir())

Answer (score 0):

it was restricted from google. below android 7 only u can create a folder inside internal folder. after that u only can create folder inside downloads,music and alarm

```
File folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File file = new File(folder, "example.txt");
if (!file .exists()){
    file .mkdirs();
}else{

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Finally it worked in Android 10**

//by Using This Method

```
  private void createFolder(String name) {
    File mydir = getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(name); //Creating an internal directory;
    if (!mydir.exists()) {
        mydir.mkdirs();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Created" + " -> " + mydir.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

    }
```